# Proper way to finish Tesseract API

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, segmentation-fault

I'm implementing OCR app which uses Tesseract API. When I press Android home button, popup window "Unfortunately  has stopped" appears. I'm running TessbaseAPI multiple times in OCR thread with handler defined. I send messages with image for OCR purposes and thread process it.

After every image I call Tessbase's `clear()` and at Activity's `onPause()` method `end()`. There is probably problem in calling `end()` while image is processed. Does anyone have advice how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Logcat error:

```
03-13 13:18:56.882: A/libc(24730): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 24756 (Thread-6411)
```

ndk-stack output:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.3/JWR66Y/776638:user/release-keys'
pid: 24730, tid: 24756, name: Thread-6411  >>> cz.skywall.dp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000010
Stack frame #00  pc 000cb132  /data/app-lib/cz.skywall.dp-1/libtess.so (ExtractIntFeat(TBLOB*, DENORM const&, INT_FEATURE_STRUCT*, INT_FEATURE_STRUCT*, INT_FX_RESULT_STRUCT*, int*)+49): Unable to open symbol file /home/lukas/Stažené/tess-two-    master/tess-two/libs/armeabi/libtess.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor
Stack frame #01  pc 000c1715  /data/app-lib/cz.skywall.dp-1/libtess.so (tesseract::Classify::GetCharNormFeatures(TBLOB*, DENORM const&, INT_TEMPLATES_STRUCT*, INT_FEATURE_STRUCT*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, int*, int*)+56): Unable to open symbol file /home/lukas/Stažené/tess-two-master/tess-two/libs/armeabi/libtess.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor
Stack frame #02  pc 000c1e3d  /data/app-lib/cz.skywall.dp-1/libtess.so (tesseract::Classify::CharNormClassifier(TBLOB*, DENORM const&, INT_TEMPLATES_STRUCT*, ADAPT_RESULTS*)+84): Unable to open symbol file /home/lukas/Stažené/tess-two-master/tess-two/libs/armeabi/libtess.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor
Stack frame #03  pc 000c27a1  /data/app-lib/cz.skywall.dp-1/libtess.so (tesseract::Classify::DoAdaptiveMatch(TBLOB*, DENORM const&, ADAPT_RESULTS*)+100): Unable to open symbol file /home/lukas/Stažené/tess-two-master/tess-two/libs/armeabi/libtess.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor
Stack frame #04  pc 000c285b  /data/app-lib/cz.skywall.dp-1/libtess.so (tesseract::Classify::AdaptiveClassifier(TBLOB*, DENORM const&, BLOB_CHOICE_LIST*, CP_RESULT_STRUCT*)+90): Unable to open symbol file /home/lukas/Stažené/tess-two-master/tess-two/libs/armeabi/libtess.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Only solution for me was to end the api after the getUTF8Text returned. E.g. if you have a thread that runs until canceled with a loop, do it after the loop.